# Keeping count in non-tail recursion

Tags: recursion, count, ml

I am writing several recursive functions in a functional language(ML), and in several of them it is necessary to keep count. I am not allowed to use tail recursion, or helper functions. How should I keep count?

For example if one problem calls for me to remove the nth element of a string, how can I know the recursive function has been called n times, before dropping that element?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the count as a parameter. I don't know ML, but in C-style languages it's done like so:

```
void processTreeNode(Node* node, int count) {

    foreach(Node* child in node->children) {
        processTreeNode( child, count + 1 );
    }
}
```

The first call usually has a value of `0` or `1`:

```
Node* root = ...
processTreeNode( root, 1 );
```

Note the above example actually counts **depth** rather than iteration count.

If you want to count the number of times the function has actually been called, you can use either a value in global state (a bad idea) or a thread-local value passed by reference:

```
void processTreeNode(Node* node, int* count) {

    (*count)++;

    foreach(Node* child in node->children) {
        processTreeNode( child, count );
    }
}
```

With the first call responsible for creating the value and reference:

```
Node* root = ...
int   count = 0;
processTreeNode( root, &count );
```

This can be generalised to an algorithm "context" object which is passed to all function calls - if it's passed by-reference then this avoids needless value-copying and stack space allocations, as well as being thread-safe provided no other thread has access to it:

```
class MyAlgorithmContext {
    int foo;
    string bar;
}

Node* root = ...
MyAlgorithmContext context;
context.foo = 123;
processTreeNode( root, &context );
```